# Многопоточность на android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, glsurfaceview

Я разрабатываю приложение под android, и уже в течении долгого времени не могу решить одну проблему, а именно:

У меня есть фрагмент, в котором surfaceview с потоком рисования для постоянной перерисовки. Само рисование работает отлично, но вот переключение между страницами - это целая проблема. Я пробовал кучу способов, дабы решить эту проблему. `Executor` использовал, пробовал возвращать return при переключении, ещё несколько способов и всё без толку. 
Вот мой код создания surfaceview

```
 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (drawThread == null || drawThread.getState() == Thread.State.TERMINATED) {
        drawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder(), getContext());
        drawThread.setRunning(true);
        executorThread.submit(drawThread);
    }
    if (!drawThread.isAlive())
        drawThread.start();
```

Это мой последний вариант реализации создания потока рисования в surfaceview 
В методе `surfaceDestroyed()` ничего нет на данный момент.
Вот поток рисования:

```
public void run() { 
    Canvas canvas;

    while (mRunning) {
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                drawGridLine(canvas);
                drawGridText(canvas);
                drawAxis(canvas);
                if (!isOverMathCalc && !isZoom)
                    drawGraphics(canvas);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) { /* */ }
        finally {
            if (canvas != null)
                mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

Как мне сделать нормальное завершение потока рисования и потом очередной его запуск после того, как мы опять перешли на страницу рисования. Так как иначе при переключении фрагментов программа тормозит, переключение происходит при помощи `NavigatorDrawer`.